# image preview on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.fn.exists = function(){console.log(this);return this.length>0;}
    var lisiz=$('ul.imagelist li').size();
    $('ul.imagelist li:lt(3)').addClass('active');
      $('ul.imagelist li:lt(3)').addClass('active');
          var lisiz = $('ul.imagelist li').size();
          if(lisiz<1){
            $('.loadmore h3').html('No Images');
          }
          $('.loadmore').on('click', function() {
                    $('ul.imagelist').find('li.active').last().nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('active');
            if (!$('ul.imagelist li').not('.active').length) {
              $('.loadmore').text('All' + " " + lisiz + ' images showen, No images to show');
            }
      });
     jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
    $('ul.imgmodal li').on('click',function(){
    $('ul.imgmodal li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    //var imgli = $('ul.imgmodal li.active');
    var imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
    $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

    });

//click next
        $('.next').on('click',function(){
            if ($('ul.imgmodal li.active').next('ul.imgmodal li').exists()) {
                var imgli=$('ul.imgmodal li.active').next('ul.imgmodal li');
                $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
                imgli.addClass('active');
                 imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
                $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
                //alert(imgadress);
            }else{
                    $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('ul.imgmodal li').first().addClass('active');
                     imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
                    $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
                    //alert(imgadress);
                }


        });
        //click prew
        $('.prev').on('click',function(){

            if($('ul.imgmodal li.active').prev('ul.imgmodal li').exists()){
                var prev = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').prev('ul.imgmodal li');
                $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
                prev.addClass('active');
                 imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
                $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
                //alert(imgadress);
            }else{
                $('.modalimg img').animate({
                width:'100%'
                });
                $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('ul.imgmodal li').last().addClass('active');
                 imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
                $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);

                //alert(imgadress);
            }
        });
 });
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
 }
ul.imagelist li{
    width:20%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: none;

}
ul.imagelist li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.imagelist li.active{
    display: inline-block;
}
.loadmore{
cursor: pointer;
color:red;
}
.imgmodal li{
 width: 20%;
 min-width: 260px;
 margin: 5px;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
.imgmodal li img{
width:100%;
height: 200px;
 }
.modalimg img{
width:100%;
height: 300px;
text-align: center;
}
.cler{
 clear: both;
 }
.prev,.next,.imgmodal li{
cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainone text-center">
    <ul class="imagelist list-inline text-center imgmodal">
    <li><img src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img7.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img7.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img8.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img7.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/img8.jpg"></li>

    </ul>
    <span class="loadmore"><h3>load more</h3></span>
    </div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-body modalimg">
    <img src="images/6.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <h3><span class="prev pull-left">prev</span><span class="pull-right clearfix next">next</span><span class="cler"></span></h3>
  </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

After loading the document displays three images, whenever i click on the image, an image preview will be displayed in a bootstrap modal and if i click next or prev,  these options also work. However when I close the modal only one image is displayed.

Comment: after you see the modal and you close it, you get the one image where if you click on your "All 14 images showen..." then again your images load back.Check it and try to use a window.reload or set time once you close the modal to get to the first three images.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/YEkAt/586/

Comment: this is updated link

Comment: i did correct what i did mistake

Comment: i hav only 15 vots so i can not post currect answer please give upvote i will post currect answer

Comment: okay, what is your actual mistake you did and to post answer you dont have to care about reputation and I will do that for you.

Comment: i have only 15 reputation  with this 15 reputation server wil not allow me to post,while i am posting it is showing error ,it is good question thats why i am asking reputation ,you can see my currect answer    jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/YEkAt/586

Comment: okay, have it and post your answer. So it will be easy for others to understand.And some of your images is not loading up. Look at it as well in the fiddle.

Comment: thanks to all who has voted me,today we have given good example to our viewers

Answer (score 1):

i got answer just change 3 lines of jquery after 
  $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); this line adde 3 lines code and change active varible to activemodl[     updated fiddle link here][1]

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery.fn.exists = function(){console.log(this);return this.length>0;}
    var lisiz=$('ul.imagelist li').size();
   // $('ul.imagelist li:lt(3)').addClass('active');
  $('ul.imagelist li:lt(3)').addClass('active');
      var lisiz = $('ul.imagelist li').size();
      if(lisiz<1){
        $('.loadmore h3').html('No Images');
      }
      $('.loadmore').on('click', function() {
                   $('ul.imagelist').find('li.active').last().nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('active');
        if (!$('ul.imagelist li').not('.active').length) {
          $('.loadmore').text('All' + " " + lisiz + ' images showen, No images to show');
        }
      });
      jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
    $('ul.imgmodal li').on('click',function(){
    $('ul.imgmodal li').removeClass('activemodl');
   $(this).addClass('activemodl');
    var imgli = $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl');
    var imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').find("img:first").attr("src");
    $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    var activSize=$('ul.imagelist li.active');
    $('ul.imagelist li:lt(activSize)').addClass('active');
    });

     //click next
       $('.next').on('click',function(){
        if ($('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').next('ul.imgmodal li').exists()) {
            var imgli=$('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').next('ul.imgmodal li');
            $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').removeClass('activemodl');
            imgli.addClass('activemodl');
             imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').find("img:first").attr("src");
            $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
            //alert(imgadress);
        }else{
                $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').removeClass('activemodl');
                $('ul.imgmodal li').first().addClass('activemodl');
                 imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.activemodl').find("img:first").attr("src");
                $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
                //alert(imgadress);
            }


    });
    //click prew
    $('.prev').on('click',function(){

        if($('ul.imgmodal li.active').prev('ul.imgmodal li').exists()){
            var prev = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').prev('ul.imgmodal li');
            $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
            prev.addClass('active');
             imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
            $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);
            //alert(imgadress);
        }else{
            $('.modalimg img').animate({
            width:'100%'
            });
            $('ul.imgmodal li.active').removeClass('active');
            $('ul.imgmodal li').last().addClass('active');
             imgadress = $('ul.imgmodal li.active').find("img:first").attr("src");
            $('.modalimg img').attr('src',imgadress);

            //alert(imgadress);
        }
    });
  });

</script>
```

updated fiddle [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/YEkAt/591/

Comment: Do have a look at your pop up modal when you click an image. It seems to be that in your fiddle when you click the previous button for the first time, it doesn't work properly. Set some window.setTimeout if you can so that it works better.As you wished I gave you enough reputation. Cheers.

Comment: i dont know where i want to put "window.setTimeout " can you plz help me

Comment: its not only window.setTimeout, you can also window.setInterval in any case. I'm not saying to do this for now. But have a look for the future.Now its okay as you said you are a newbie.